# ARM TTK throwing error for the test : Location Should Not Be Hardcoded in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

I am running ARM TTK as one of the tasks in my Azure DevOps Pipeline for validating ARM Templates before a PR is merged.
One of the tests that i am using is : **Location Should Not Be Hardcoded** which is mentioned in the link : [ARM-TTK-Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-test-cases#resources-should-have-location) by the name of "**Location Uses Parameter**"

My ARM Template name is not "azuredeploy.json" or "mainTemplate.json" . My ARM Template name is "winvm-arm.json".
I have the location defined in parameters like shown below :

```
"location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
```

I also have the reference to this parameter in my resource block like shown below :

```
resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), '-nic')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

So everything is correct as per what it should be then why is the test still flagging the error below :

```
Location Should Not Be Hardcoded (12 ms) 
        The location parameter of nested templates must not have a defaultValue property. It is "[resourceGroup().location]"
```

Is it because my main template name is not "azuredeploy.json" or "mainTemplate.json"  and it is being treated as a nested template , is that the reason

Comment: As per the example, the template portion you shared looks all right. Are there any additional resources you're deploying in the template? Can you share the complete template?

Comment: What i did was i renamed my template from "winvm-arm.json" to just "azuredeploy.json" and it is no longer flagging the error for the above test. So this is quite strange as i cannot be having all my JSON files by the name of azuredeploy.json right. So if i put any other name, then the test is thinking that my template is a linked template and highlighting the error related to the test. So is this a bug or how to ensure that the test doesn't catch this error even though the name of the JSON file is not azuredeploy.json or mainTemplate.json

Comment: From [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/test-toolkit#test-parameters): `To test one file in that folder, add the -File parameter. However, the folder must still have a main template named azuredeploy.json or maintemplate.json.`.

Comment: This is the command that i am running and it is one my tasks in Azure DevOps : get-childitem -Recurse "C:\Pallab\ARM Templates\*.json" | Test-AzTemplate

Comment: It is not possible for me to specify individual files as this will be part of a pipeline and the pipeline will kick in tests whenever a push happens to Azure Repos and before a PR is merged

Comment: As mentioned above, you would need to name your main template as either `azuredeploy.json` or `maintemplate.json`. That's how ARM-TTK is coded. If you wish, you could raise an issue on the Github repo for this project.

Comment: Thank you @Garurav Mantri and @ Pallab. You can refer to open GitHub issue at ["Location Should Not Be Hardcoded" test catching errors in good templates](https://github.com/Azure/arm-ttk/issues/508)

Comment: Yes it is raised by me only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Brian Moore](https://github.com/bmoore-msft). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> this is because anything that is not the "main template" is assumed to be a nested template... main template is determined by the filename (unless you specify otherwise).

> I think short term you'll have to follow the pattern - until we have a more standard way of determining name / nested.

You can refer to ["Location Should Not Be Hardcoded" test catching errors in good templates](https://github.com/Azure/arm-ttk/issues/508#issuecomment-931684243)